# Java 1.6 methods of the String class doesn't work with all characters

Tags: java, string, methods, char, character

I have a String that consists of characters like "ò, ý, ü, û, ú, ù, ÷, ö, ï, î". Before the class is compiled with Java 1.6, methods like `myString.split("ý");` or `myString.contains("ý");` work. After the class is compiled by using the command line the methods doesn't work with these characters.
I have to use Java 1.6.

Is there any way to avoid this problem?

Comment: How does it work before you compile it? Have you invented your own Java interpreter that can run Java source code directly without compiling it?

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: @Andreas I run it with Eclipse that probably use Java 1.8. With compiling I mean compiling with Java 1.6 and export it to a jar.

Comment: Try by verifying the difference in encoding

Comment: Agree with @DanielJipa. Your problem is likely the encoding of the source file. Is the file in UTF-8? If so, try specifying the encoding when compiling the file. Eclipse will usually manage this for you, so I'm assuming you're talking about compiling from the command-line.

Comment: @Andreas For example I have a String "abcýabc" and call the split method with "ý" as a parameter on it, it returns "abcýabc". But it should return "abc" and "abc".

Comment: Actually, Java 6, 7, and 8 all say *"If `-encoding` is not specified, the platform default converter is used."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Java source files are stored in the platform default encoding, and that is how `javac` reads the files if `-encoding` is not specified.

If you type/paste characters into a source file in Eclipse, Eclipse will automatically change the encoding to UTF-8 (I believe it prompts you first, but I'm not sure).

In Eclipse, every Java source can theoretically be in different encodings. Eclipse remembers the encoding of every source file, and you can see and/or change that encoding in the files Property dialog in Eclipse.

If Eclipse has changed the encoding to UTF-8, then compiling in Eclipse will work fine, but compiling outside, e.g. by calling `javac` or using Ant, will not work, because they will by default read the source file using the platform default encoding.

So, if you have a mixture of source file encodings, you must change them all to the same encoding, so using `javac` can specify that common encoding. You have two choices:

- Convert all files to UTF-8, and specify `-encoding UTF-8`.
- Convert all files to platform default encoding, and use unicode escapes for characters that are not supported by that encoding, which for `ý` is [`\u00FD`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00fd/index.htm).